# KDE Dolphin: revert to previous spacebar behavior

Tags: linux, kde, dolphin-file-manager

In 2022, Dolphin has added the "selection mode", described here: https://pointieststick.com/2022/08/19/this-week-in-kde-dolphin-selection-mode/
In my personal workflows, I was relying heavily on the previous behavior of the spacebar shortcut. The post above hints that there is a way to disable the selection mode, but I didn't find it. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

More googling found https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/105ejyq and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=458282 from which I can use ctrl-space to recreate the old behavior.

There is a setting to change the keyboard shortcut that enable the selection mode, called "select files and folders", but in the current debian 12.4 (Dolphin 22.12.3), it defaults to "none" even if spacebar works as a shortcut. Defining a shortcut there activates a second shortcut, but spacebar stays assigned to "selection mode" as well. I'm tempted to report this as a bug, but given that I'm testing code that's a year old, it wouldn't make sense.

That'll have to do for now.